# Did all integrated Commodore PET monitors always use 60 Hz refresh?

Tags: commodore, crt-monitor, commodore-pet

All models of the Commodore PET line had built-in monitors, and at least the U.S. models had 60 Hz refresh. For the European models there was no need for compatibility with European television standards as far as I'm aware; did they also use 60 Hz refresh? Were there any situations in which a PET monitor did not use 60 Hz refresh?

If they all did, was the same true of the CBM-II hi-profile models with their built-in monitors?

Comment: While they didn't have to use European broadcast TV standards like PAL, they did have to run off 50 Hz European power.  Mains is usually the source of the 50 or 60 Hz vertical blank in a cheap CRT.

Comment: @RETRAC: Mains isn't usable as a source of vertical blanking, since there's no fixed relationship between line phase and broadcast frames.  On displays without good high-voltage filtering, image geometry will be affected by the phase relationship between line phase and video frames, which would create annoying shuddering if the rates weren't reasonably close, but a typical computer's video output won't be close enough to US mains frequency to prevent such effects in the absence of good HV filtering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The early PET models (all 2001, early 30xx) with discrete video circuitry used 60 Hz in all models worldwide.

The later PET models (later 30xx, 40xx/80xx/8x96/9000) used a 6545 CRTC chip where the ROM could set the refresh rate. (These can usually be identified by the ROM providing BASIC 4.0.) Candian/U.S. ROMs set a 60 Hz refresh rate; European ROMs set a 50 Hz refresh rate. There was indeed no technical reason to use different refresh rates; it's not known why they did this.

The CBM-II series also used different refresh rates between country models. Certainly many of the series 600/700 models in Sweden and Germany were using 50 Hz refresh. But perhaps not all: there were a wide variety of ROMs for the CBM-II systems, none fully developed, so whether any particular unit, regardless of country, used 60 Hz or 50 Hz can be hard to tell.

Comment: Not really sure why you think it's a good idea to just copy information form another question. But when doing so, you should at least not twist it - like I didn't mention any difference between 600 and 700 or them being send to different countries. Also, it's not many not fully developed, but all - the CBM-II series development was never finished at all. Each and every version known got some bugs. Only he after market CBUG development is kind of a standard.

Comment: @Raffzahn I rewrote your answer because I found it hard to understand many details: a perfect example of that, as you (perhaps inadvterantly) pointed out in your comment is that the 600/700 thing.. Can you explain what I got wrong there?

Comment: I have no idea what went wrong. For some reason you assign 600 units to Sweden and 700 to Germany. Why?

Comment: @Raffzahn Because that's exactly what you do in your answer: "600/700 units for Sweden and Germany." So what are these "600 units" and how are they relevant to the question?

Comment: 600/700 are the CBM-II models. What else? And there are Swedish and German versions of both. And it's relevant, as they use 50 Hz refresh.  And they are to be distinct from the 500s, as these are even less finalized. Here almost every unit differs.

Comment: I think, @Raffzahn has a fair point here: It may be better to clearly state the intent at the beginning of the answer. This may be also useful for anyone who reads this, as a hint on this being not first-hand information, but rather a rephrasing of an original information provided elsewhere. (But I'm not a mod here, this is just an opinion.)

Answer (score 10):

**TL;DR:**

Non-CRTC PETs (Original PET, early 30xx) are fixed to 60 Hz.

CRTC (6545) based PETs (40xx/80xx/8x96/9000 - *1) use screen refresh rates set by their ROM (*2). 50 Hz for European machines, 60 Hz for US/Canadian units.

---

**Regarding the details:**

> For the European models there was no need for compatibility with European television standards as far as I'm aware;

You're right. As a self contained system, there is no need to synchronize to any external source. Why Commodore switched to 50 Hz seems strange. There is no technical need or legal need to do so.

> did they also use 60 Hz refresh? Were there any situations in which a PET monitor did not use 60 Hz refresh?

Early PETs did. Later ones did not. The majority of European units did use 50 Hz.

> was the same true of the CBM-II hi-profile models with their built-in monitors

Basically yes (as well as for external screens). So 'regular' 600/700 units for Sweden and Germany (distinct because of different keyboard) used a 50 Hz refresh. Except 'regular' is a wide array here, as there is a wide variety of ROMs for the CBM-II series, all of them at best beta versions. So yes, they did use 50 Hz, but which ones did or did not is hard to tell.

---

*1 - As a generalization this means all BASIC 4.0 machines.

*2 - The ROMs differ as well within the editor ROM for keyboard layout.

Comment: Presumably the 60 and 50Hz outputs otherwise match standard video timings? A 4:3 display, 63.55µs or 64µs scans, ~263 or ~312 lines per field, etc? If I took the screen out of a PET, I could probably route suitably-decoded standard definition video to it?

Comment: Matching CRT refresh rate to the local grid AC rate makes for a better display because it minimizes bad interactions with AC rate flicker of lights.

Comment: @Tommy yes. After all, the original PET screens were pretty standard TV tubes :))

Comment: @GeorgePhillips There's always a flicker, as they are never really synchronized.

Comment: @Raffzahn: I don't think the issue is so much flicker as line-phase-dependent screen geometry.  Feed a VIC-20's output into a TV with bad high-voltage filtering and the screen geometry will "breathe" somewhat annoyingly, in a way that can be reduced by enabling interlacing (which adjusts the frame rate closer to 60Hz).

Comment: I find this answer difficult to read; I think you're saying the same thing in three different ways in three separate pargraphs, and then talking about the CBM-IIs in the fourth. Would it be possible for you to rewrite this, dropping the quotes and instead focusing on telling the story here as clearly as possible, regardless of the particular format of the original question?

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson Not really sure what you want to read - the answer is rather simple structured in two parts - a short TLDR summing all easy points as short and clear as possible. Followed by a longer section (clearly seperated, isn't it?) - going into issues as listed. Also, the CBM-II issue isn't as simple/clear as with all the original series due the fact that existing machines are a patchwork of half done versions and hardware.

Comment: @Raffzahn I've added an answer that shows what I prefer to read. Let me know if I differ in anything you said or missed important information related to the question.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson Well, if you want me to write what you want to read, there's a simple solution: I'l send you my contract, and will deliver, at standard rates, any wording you want to read. Until then, I rather give you the respect to answer the question like it's asked.

Comment: Well, sorry I don't feel you're giving me respect when you tell me I'm wrong to desire a focused rather than meandering answer, but I'm sure you'll "respect" me even harder by telling me that my definition of "respect" as "an attitude of consideration" is wrong.